# sending data to node.js/socket.io server from JAVA

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to send a message to my node.js/socket.io server via Java

Here is the code i am using to send the message

```
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

class socketMessage {

    public socketMessage() {
    }

    public static void send(String string) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Sending message to Socket Server!");

        URL url = new URL("http://<mysite>:8000");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        try (OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream())) {
            System.out.println("Data Sent!");
            writer.write(string);
            writer.flush();
        }
        conn.getResponseCode(); // Thanks to BGR
    }
}
```

called with: `socketMessage.send("Admin|notification|Logged in elsewhere\n> Official Java App");`

and here is the server code:

```
var http = require("http");
var io = require('socket.io');

var sessionsConnections = {};
var whereIsUserVisitingFrom = {};

console.log("\n\n-------------------------------- Server Started --------------------------------");

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){ 
    var body = '';
    req.on('data', function(data){
        console.log('Received Data');
        body += data;
    });
    req.on('end', function() {
        // Emit the data to all clients
        ioServer.emit('message', { message: body });
    });
});
server.listen(8000);

var ioServer = io.listen(server, { log: false });

ioServer.on('connection', function(socket) {

    var currentUser;

    var parts;

    socket.on('started', function(data) {
        currentUser = data.username;
        sessionsConnections[currentUser] = socket.id;
        whereIsUserVisitingFrom[currentUser] = data.from;
        socket.emit("connected", { message: "Welcome, " + currentUser + "!" });

        socket.broadcast.emit("updateUsers", { message: sessionsConnections, from: whereIsUserVisitingFrom });
        socket.emit("updateUsers", { message: sessionsConnections, from: whereIsUserVisitingFrom });
    });

    socket.on('message', function(data) {
        var parts = data.message.split("|");

        socket.broadcast.emit("updateUsers", { message: sessionsConnections, from: whereIsUserVisitingFrom });
        socket.emit("updateUsers", { message: sessionsConnections, from: whereIsUserVisitingFrom });

        console.log("Message Recieved!");

        if( parts[0] == "*" ) {
            socket.broadcast.emit("display", { message: data.message });
        }else{
            if( parts[0] in sessionsConnections ) {
                io.sockets.socket(sessionsConnections[parts[0]]).emit("display", { message: data.message });
            }else{
                socket.emit("display", { message: "That user is not online!" });
            }
        }
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        delete sessionsConnections[currentUser];
        socket.broadcast.emit("updateUsers", { message: sessionsConnections, from: whereIsUserVisitingFrom });
        socket.emit("updateUsers", { message: sessionsConnections, from: whereIsUserVisitingFrom });
    });

});
```

basically what my server does currently is when I visit my website, then send a command from my Admin Center in the form of "{user}|{action (i.e. notification)}|{text/extra_param(s)}" it will send a message to the client of whom you set as the {user} and then I have code on the client side that splits that message into parts and changes the websites UI accordingly, but I also want to do this from my Java app, and it ain't working :(

any ideas

Vinny

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you define "not working"? error? timeout? ...??

Comment: The server just isnt recieving the data, I have my server writing to the console everytime it receives data, I don't know how I would check for errors or timeouts, I'm guessing they would show up on the java client side in the Netbeans output console, if so there are no errors/timeouts displaying

Answer (score 1):

To complete the HTTP connection, the HTTP response must be read.

Insert `conn.getResponseCode()` after the `try` block

Comment: I added this, but my node server is not receiving the message :/

Comment: @MRVDOG What is the value of `conn.getResponseCode()`?

Comment: conn.getResponseCode() returns '200'

Comment: @MRVDOG Your server did receive a connection an replied. Run a debugger server side, your client looks fine or is not sending any content

Comment: okay I will do, I have work now, so will try when I get home, thanks for your help. I will let you know how it goes

Answer (score 0):

After add

```java
conn.getResponseCode()
```

still not make this work.
Finally I found [socket.io-java-client](https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client)  exactly what we need。Because socket.io not use orginal websocket which you use but add a protocl on it, and your code "data" event will never triggered.